# C Programming - Viewing struct content by memory address

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I have a linked list with several nodes.
If I know the address to one of the node, is there a way to view the content by the address?

Example code:

```
//--------------------------------
// Setting up a list of nodes
//--------------------------------
struct node {
    int value;
    struct node *next;
};

int main(void) {
    struct node *first = NULL;
    struct node *new_node;

    // setting up first node
    new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new_node->value = 1;
    new_node->next = first;    
    first = new_node;

    // setting up second node
    new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new_node->value = 2;
    new_node->next = first;
    first = new_node;

    // setting up third node
    new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new_node->value = 3;
    new_node->next = first;
    first = new_node;

    return 0;
}
```

During debug w/ GDB, I have a break point set to `return 0`

Under Debug console in VSCODE, I can view the address to `first` with `*&first`, which is just `first`

Example

```
  first
  0x6888fffb20
    value: 1
    next: 0x25acadb18c0
      value: 2
      next: 0x25acadb1880
        value: 3
        next: 0x0 // NULL
          value: 
          next:
```

If I want to manipulate the 2nd node (its value, or its next node pointer), is there a way to do so directly with the address `0x52acadb18c0`?

Note, the address to each node has no direct relationship w/ one another, i.e., `first + or - (some memory offset)` will not work in this case.

Comment: Your pointer variable `new_node` *is* the address of the new node.  If you're asking "Can I cast the hex value to an address and use that as a pointer," I suppose that's possible, but I wouldn't wish that on my worst enemy.

Comment: "cast the hex value to an address and use that as a pointer", i.e., `(struct node *) 0x52acadb18c0`. That is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: If it's the 2nd node, why not `first->next-value = 42` and flavours of that?

Comment: The motivation is that, during debug, I may lose the access to certain nodes via `first` i.e., such node may be deleted or replaced by a different list, and I still want to view their content by a pre-recorded address value.

Comment: I'm glad you seem to have found an answer you like. Just wanted to suggest that your sample could code could use `new_node1, new_node2, ...` instead of reusing a single variable. These variables would retain the address assigned regardless of how the LL changes. You could examine them in the debugger with ease! (Caveat: accessing free'd memory is venturing into UB.)

Comment: The actual code is much longer  and complex than the sample code I am showing here. But I understand what you are saying. What is UB?

Answer (score 0):

What I was looking for was to cast the hex value to a struct node pointer.

`(struct node *) 0x52acadb18c0`